# Turn a list of words in a path string in BSD Make

Tags: path, tex, bsdmake

I am preparing a `Makefile` for a TeX document and I want to customize the `TEXINPUTS` environment variable, as follows:

The `Makefile` says

```
TEXINPUTS= figures
TEXINPUTS+= chapter1
TEXINPUTS+= chatper2

galley.pdf: ${SRCS}
    env TEXINPUTS="${TEXINPUTSPATH}" ${TEX} galley.tex
```

Where `TEXINPUTSPATH` should be `figures:chapter1:chapter2:`.

How can I compute `TEXINPUTSPATH` from `TEXINPUTS` with BSD Make?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The naive approach `TEXINPUTSPATH=${TEXINPUTS:S/ /:}` will not work, because the substitution commanded by `S` is done on each word of `TEXINPUTS`.  Luckily, we can use `Q` to quote each space and turn `TEXINPUTS` into a single word:

```
TEXINPUTSPATH=${TEXINPUTS:Q:S/\ /:/g}
```